# Vertically Center & Stretch Row-Oriented Flexbox

Tags: css, flexbox

I am trying to create what is basically a horizontally/row-oriented version of Bootstrap v4's cards using flexbox (`flex-direction: row`). Instead of having a header, I'd like to have a left column that would contain the card's icon while the right column would contain the text for the card. I have this about 95% complete, except for the fact that when I vertically center the left column, it no longer takes up the entire vertical spacing (see the black areas surrounding the yellow `.icon` div in the CodePen example below). If I tell the column to stretch itself (change the `align-self` property of the `.icon` class to `stretch`), the column loses its vertical centering.

How can I make the left/yellow/`.icon` column be vertically centered **and** cover all vertical space?

The CodePen example has the parent and child divs colored to show the area they are occupying, but in my final product only the `.icon` div will have a background color. The other two divs (`.wrapper` and `.content`) will not have any background color. I prefer to not have to set the vertical height of the card, but if that is the only way to do what I want to accomplish, it won't be a deal breaker.

[CodePen.io example](http://codepen.io/HokieCoder/pen/bpydyX)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can inbricate flex boxe to use alignements also in children.

Not too sure of what you look for exactly, but here an example of inbrication and use of flexbox to center things:

wrapper in middle of screen and content icon also in middle

```css
html {
 display:flex;
 height:100%;/* give an height or min-height to that flex boxe */
}
body {/* single element, easy to middle center */
 margin:auto;/* or justify-content+align-items center on html */
}
.wrapper {
 background-color: black;
 color: white;
 display: flex;
 flex-flow: row nowrap;
 min-height: 100%;
 width: 300px
}

.icon {
 display:flex;/* flex child can be a flex boxe too */
 align-items:center;
 background-color: yellow;
 color: black;
 flex: 1 1 auto;
 font-size: 32px;
 padding: 20px;
}

.content {
 background-color: lightgreen;
 color: black;
 flex: 12 1 auto;
 padding: 20px;
}
h4 {
  margin:0 0 10px;
  }

/* where is body ? */
body {
  box-shadow:0 0 0 5px white, 0 0 0 15px tomato;
  }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
 <div class="icon">
  @
 </div>
 <div class="content">
  <h4>Application #1</h4>
  <p>This is an application of flexbox. Tomato color is shadowed from body.</p>
 </div>
</div>
```

**[pen forked](http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/LNoNLy)**

Comment: Perfect! What I was missing was continuing the flexbox model down into the `.icon` div. I didn't have to change anything with the `html` or `body` elements. On the surface (in my opinion, at least) it doesn't make sense that you need to do that, but after seeing it in action it makes more sense. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!